# Copy a temporary structure using malloc and a void pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, embedded, avr

I have the following function which is being called as the start to a module for a program on an embedded AVR clock. I want to get the value from the clock object which will return a date_time structure and copy it into the space I am allocating from the heap.

```
void time_set_mode_start(Display *display, volatile Controls *controls,
                         volatile TimeKeeper *clock, void *data) {

    DEBUG_LED_PORT |= _BV(DEBUG_LED);
    data = malloc(sizeof(date_time));
}
```

What is the best way to get data the value returned from clock->getTime() into the data pointer?

Comment: There isn't [enough information](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete and concise. What's the interface spec for `TimeKeeper::getTime`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use [`memcpy`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/memcpy.3.html). Specifically, you would probably want `memcpy(data, clock->getTime(), sizeof(date_time))`.

Another way — probably better, now that I think about it — is to use ordinary assignment:

```
*((date_time*)data) = *(clock->getTime());
```

This treats `data` as a `date_time *`, and assigns a value to the `date_time` object that it points to.

(Note: in both of the above code-snippets, I'm assuming that `clock->getTime()` returns a `date_time *`. Is that correct?)

By the way, I should point out that `data = malloc(sizeof(date_time));` will completely replace the original `void * data` that was passed in. Your caller will never see the memory location that `data` now points to, because the pointer is being passed by value.

Comment: In this case would need to modify getTime() to return a pointer vs the actually struct? I tried doing something similar by creating a temporary structure and then passing it's address to memcpy. All I got was garbage data and I believe I got a segfault however I can't tell on this embedded system..

Comment: @secretformula: As you were posting your question, I was completely rewriting my answer. What I originally wrote was pretty facile, sorry.

Comment: Thank you this looks like it would work. I will create a separate method that returns a `date_time*`. I do intend to completely replace what ever is in there. It will have been freed by another module's end method. I will accept in 4 mins when I am able

Comment: @secretformula: Maybe it's just that you trimmed the code-snippet so much that some relevant code is missing, but -- why are you even passing in a `data` pointer? Your current code-snippet never writes to the pointer that was passed in; it just writes to new space that the caller never sees. Jonathan Leffler's answer below suggests (as one possibility) that your prototype should have `void ** pdata` instead of `void * data`, and I think he's right that that's what you have in mind.

Comment: Whats happening is the program is modular. The clock has multiple functions i.e. Time, Time set... I wanted to be able to easily add and remove these fuctions. So i have a 2d array of function pointers. Each modual has 3 functions: start, update, end. Each of the 3 fuctions has the prototype above. This function posted above is the start function which i want to allocate space on the temp pointer it is passed. It will then work with this space in the update method, then free it in the end method. Please tell me if there is a better way./ Is the a better place to discourse this?

Comment: @secretformula: The problem is that you're *not* allocating space on the temp pointer it is passed. You're allocating space, and setting `data` to point to that space; but the temp pointer that was passed is still pointing to wherever it was pointing before. (It's like if your function accepted an `int i`, and then had `i = 3;`. That would change `i`, but it wouldn't change the integer that was passed. The caller wouldn't see the 3. This is the same thing, only the value is a `void *` instead of an `int`.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5219/discussion-between-secretformula-and-ruakh)

Answer (score 0):

Either the calling code needs to allocate the space for the value and pass that into the function shown as the `data` parameter, or the function prototype needs to have `void **data` so that the function can pass the value back.  As it stands, your code overwrites the local copy of `data` with a newly allocated value, which then leaks memory on return.

Assuming the prototype of `date_time TimeKeeper::getTime()`:

```
void time_set_mode_start(Display *display, volatile Controls *controls,
                         volatile TimeKeeper *clock, void **pdata)
{
    DEBUG_LED_PORT |= _BV(DEBUG_LED);
    *data = malloc(sizeof(date_time));
    *(date_time *)(*data) = clock->getTime();
}
```

If the prototype is `date_time *TimeKeeper::getTime()`, then the assignment is:

```
    *(date_time *)(*data) = *clock->getTime();
```

If it is something else, you need to tell us.